# GetModuleFileNameExA won't work like it should when I try to link the function on runtime from psapi.dll (windows)

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, linker, runtime

I'm experimenting with loading functions from dlls during run-time on windows. I tried doing a program that would print it's own modules, based on this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/psapi/enumerating-all-modules-for-a-process.

I need two functions to do what i want: EnumProcessModules and GetModuleFileNameExA. I managed to get both of them from psapi.dll on runtime, however GetModuleFileNameExA just doesn't work like it should and I can't tell why

this is the functional script I have written:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <psapi.h>

typedef DWORD (__cdecl *EnumModules)(HANDLE hprocess, HMODULE *moduleHandles, DWORD cb, LPDWORD lpcNeeded);
typedef DWORD (__cdecl *GetModuleName)(HANDLE hprocess, HMODULE hmodule, LPSTR name, DWORD size);

void ErrorMessage(const char *message){
    fprintf(stderr, message);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int PrintModules( HANDLE pHandle )
{
    HMODULE hMods[1024];
    DWORD cbNeeded;
    unsigned int i;

    if (NULL == pHandle)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    // Loads the lib
    HMODULE psapiLib = LoadLibrary("C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\psapi.dll");
    if(! psapiLib) ErrorMessage("Error loading psapi.dll\n");

    // Get the functions we need from the lib
    EnumModules getModules = (EnumModules)GetProcAddress(psapiLib, "EnumProcessModules");
    GetModuleName getModuleName = (GetModuleName)GetProcAddress(psapiLib, "GetModuleFileNameExA");
    if(!getModules) ErrorMessage("Error finding EnumProcessModules from psapi.dll\n");
    if(!getModuleName) ErrorMessage("Error finding GetModuleFileNameExA from psapi.dll\n");


   // Get a list of all the modules in this process.

    if( getModules(pHandle, hMods, sizeof(hMods), &cbNeeded))
    {
        for ( i = 0; i < (cbNeeded / sizeof(HMODULE)); i++ )
        {
            LPSTR szModName;
            szModName = malloc(1024 * sizeof(LPSTR));

            // Get the full path to the module's file.

            // change GetModuleFileNameExA with getModuleName to see the error
            if ( GetModuleFileNameExA( pHandle, hMods[i], szModName, 1024 * sizeof(char))){
                // Print the module name and handle value.
                printf(("\t%s (0x%08X)\n"), szModName, hMods[i] );
                
            }

            free(szModName);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int main( void )
{
    HANDLE myHandle = GetCurrentProcess();
    PrintModules(myHandle);
    CloseHandle(myHandle);

    return 0;
}
```

If I change this part

```
if ( GetModuleFileNameExA( pHandle, hMods[i], szModName, 1024 * sizeof(char))){
                // Print the module name and handle value.
                printf(("\t%s (0x%08X)\n"), szModName, hMods[i] );
                
            }
```

to this

```
if ( getModuleName( pHandle, hMods[i], szModName, 1024 * sizeof(char))){
                // Print the module name and handle value.
                printf(("\t%s (0x%08X)\n"), szModName, hMods[i] );
                
            }
```

so it would use my function instead, taking the need to link the psapi.dll on load-time away, it just does't work. It will either segfault or not print anything. I have tried modiffing how i present the buffer, tried using widechar or Tchar but nothing seems to work.

This is the output I have with the functional script:
[working script ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgzeH.png)

and this is the output i have with my function:
[non functional script output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vssw.png)

The funny part is that one of the functions, the getModules (which points to EnumProcessModules) worked perfectly fine! I just can't understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change this line of code

```
typedef DWORD (__cdecl *EnumModules)(HANDLE hprocess, HMODULE *moduleHandles, DWORD cb, LPDWORD lpcNeeded);
```

to this.

```
typedef DWORD(__stdcall* EnumModules)(HANDLE hprocess, HMODULE* moduleHandles, DWORD cb, LPDWORD lpcNeeded);
```

for more info you can reference [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/stdcall?view=msvc-160)

Comment: Same with the `GetModuleName` typedef, too. Almost all Win32 API function use `__stdcall`, the only exceptions being functions like `wsprintf` which require `__cdecl`